# jQuery dropdown menu toggle issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click on open it toggles all of the submenus. I want to toggle only the exact `ul` under the `li`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".has-children>a").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
    });
    $('.has-children').click(function() {
        $(this).find('>ul').toggle(300);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="has-children">
    <a href="#">open</a>
        <ul class="submenu" style="display:none">
            <li class="has-children">
            <a href="#">open</a>
                <ul class="submenu" style="display:none">
                    <li>1</li>
                    <li>2</li>
                    <li>3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Try adding an id to that one and then use it

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by changing `find()` to `children()` to target only direct children of the `li`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".has-children>a").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
    });
    $('.has-children').click(function() {
        $(this).children('ul').toggle(300);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="has-children">
    <a href="#">open</a>
        <ul class="submenu" style="display:none">
            <li class="has-children">
            <a href="#">open</a>
                <ul class="submenu" style="display:none">
                    <li>1</li>
                    <li>2</li>
                    <li>3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </li>
</ul>
```

This however causes a problem where clicking on children of children will close the menu, so instead you can use `a` tag and the jQuery `next()` function to toggle instead of `children()` or `find()` like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".has-children>a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).next().toggle(300);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="has-children">
    <a href="#">open</a>
    <ul class="submenu" style="display:none">
      <li class="has-children">
        <a href="#">open</a>
        <ul class="submenu" style="display:none">
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </li>
</ul>
```

This also makes your script much shorter.